# how to change application display name phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using phonegap to implement an android application and I want to change the android application display name duo to the configured language in the application.

```
<string name="app_name">My app</string>
```

Is that possible to change this attribute???

And how can I do that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can set the name of your Application in your config.xml

the tag which defines it is

```
<name>your appname</name>
```

Comment: I mean how to access the application name dynamically from my code.

Comment: i am also new to phonegap but i think after the app is compiled you cannot change the name...but tell me if there is a way

Comment: Good as simple as that.

Answer (score 9):

you actually need to go to res -> values -> strings.xml and change:

```
<string name="app_name">Your app's name</string>
```

Comment: Doesn't Work any other way?

Answer (score 2):

In cordova project> properties> WMAppManifest.xml file you can change you app's name and icon as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible due to cordova limitation:

> (node:6193) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: The product name change
>   ( tag) in config.xml is not supported dynamically. To change
>   your product name, you have to remove, then add your ios platform
>   again.

Comment: Why downvote? Do you know that NONE of the answers above works on IOs due to limitation I mention?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try **$cordova prepare android**

Cordova prepare uses the information in the highest level config.xml file to create the platform-specific config.xml file. You modify:

<name>App Name</name></code>

in the highest level config.xml file, then run $cordova prepare android. You'll see that the config.xml in the android platform folder will then be automatically updated.

Documentation on $cordova prepare: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/#cordova-prepare-command

For anyone who has an Ionic/angularjs project, you can use $ionic cordova prepare android command, which takes the Ionic project level config.xml and automatically updates the Android platform-specific config.xml.

For example (using Angularjs with Ionic), to change the app name:

1. Change the app name in the highest level config.xml file (for me it's ionicProjectFolder --> config.xml):

<name>Change the App Name Here</name>

2. Run: $ionic cordova prepare android

That command will automatically update the config.xml file in the  Android platform folder (for me this is: IonicProjectfolder --> platforms --> Android --> res --> xml --> config.xml)

Ionic documentation on $ionic cordova prepare: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/prepare/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cordova-plugin-app-name](https://github.com/blakgeek/cordova-plugin-app-name) to manage both the ios and android versions of the name change.  The android version needs to run in an after-prepare script, so this comes in handy.